# Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 37, saw 6

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, read-csv

I want to make a dataframe of this txt file.

I tried changing delimiters or using multiple seperators or quoting csv.QUOTE_NONE, but can't read this file. please help.

```
df = pd.read_csv('../sort.txt', delimiter=',', header=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, encoding='utf-8')
df
```

file: https://github.com/absingh22/read_csv

Answer (score -1):

This is due to the .txt format file. Note that the number of separators `,` is not the same on each row. You can add the `names` parameter on the `read_csv()`:

```
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/absingh22/read_csv/main/sort.txt'
df = pd.read_csv(url,sep=',',names=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6],header=None)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('../sort.txt', header=None, quotechar='"')
print(df)
```

I think the issue is that th newlines within the double quotes which make pd.read_csv interpret them as new rows. So now parsing the file is correct, treating commas inside double quotes as part of the field rather than as delimiters.